# How can I use a WPF control inside a Windows Forms Panel control?

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

Is it possible?

I'd like to use this [control](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/WPFColorPicker.aspx) inside of a panel in my C# Winforms application. Any suggestions?

Is such a thing possible? I'm using .NET 3.5; thanks!

Comment: Here's an example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4024798/trying-to-use-the-c-spellcheck-class/4026132#4026132

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add an `ElementHost` control to your winforms panel and put the WPF control in there. See here for more details: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/calvin_hsia/archive/2007/12/11/6740119.aspx

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for the [`ElementHost` control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.forms.integration.elementhost.aspx).
You'll need to make a WPF UserControl that wraps the control, then put it in an ElementHost.