# spell checker reccommendation

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, spell-checking

have been going through here and google looking for a spellcheck solution. I see there are LOTS of items, but most of them are a year or more old...so I'm bringing the subject up for a fresh perspective. The project is a vs2010 c# winforms with currently 18 windows and growing. So definately want something easy to implement. We currently have the program being used by clients, so I would want the upgrade from their perspective to be seemless.

We currently don't require our clients to have MS Word, and we prefer to not require it. So, trying to stay away from this one.

NetSpell was looking like the solution, but once I started looking at the project, it appears to be completely abandoned.

The NHunspell was another possibility, but on their website the latest news was from Oct 2010.

I see that the WPF has the spellchecker class, and while some say it's ok to integrate with the winforms, others (such as Jon Skeet whom I find very knowledgable) say don't do it. Has this changed, because most post I see like this are over a year old...

Is there something else out there, free, that most likely won't be abandoned a week after I start using it?

Thanks,
Dave K.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Trying to use the C# SpellCheck class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4024798/trying-to-use-the-c-sharp-spellcheck-class)

Comment: Hans, yes I've seen that, it's a year old, and I've seen I think it was you and Jon Skeet debate on that being a good solution or not. Right now it looks like that may be my path, but was looking for others to input first. Thanks for posting that and here.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm "answering" this just so that it doesn't remain an 'unanswered' question.

Hans Passant gave the most viable solution to the problem ( [Trying to use the C# SpellCheck class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4024798/trying-to-use-the-c-sharp-spellcheck-class) ), please one up him there if you find it helpful as well. There is just, as he put it, nagging problem with the Font. It appears blurry next to the winforms fonts, even with changing to his suggested Segoe UI font. other then the bluriness, i haven't noticed any other problems

Comment: You should provide a code sample that answers the question or perhaps excerpts from the other post. This is basically just a link only answer. -1 until you fix it.

Comment: Thank you for your input in this matter, I will be mindful of that in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I successfully used the [spell checking included in the DevExpress WinForm](http://www.devexpress.com/products/net/controls/winforms/spell_checker/) controls. They are even capable of using [OpenOffice dictionaries](http://extensions.services.openoffice.org/en/dictionaries).

All stand-alone solutions seemed to be outdated, the last time I search for.

Comment: missed the line, "Is there something else out there, free..." -sorry.

Comment: Never found anything free. What's so bad about purchasing libraries?