# how to add spellcheck in framework 3.5

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, frameworks

i want to add textbox1 spellcheck in framework 3.5 winform but its show error, how to add spellcheck in my textbox see below code and picture.

```
 textBox1.SpellCheck.IsEnabled = true;
```

[Spellcheck Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/frZzU.jpg)

Comment: If you mean [SpellCheck](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.spellcheck(v=vs.110).aspx) from WPF, then it will not work for winforms controls, because they don't support attached properties. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23834001/1997232), might be an option for you.

Comment: i am using Winform application not WPF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Sinatr has write to you in comments - you can't use WPF Spellchecking in WinForms application.

In WinForms you need add some library. For example you can try use offline [The NetSpell project](http://www.loresoft.com/The-NetSpell-project/) It's a little bit old library. Or you can use newer but still beta  [Spell Check Winforms TextBox](https://spellchecktextbox.codeplex.com/)

UPDATE:
NetSpell is free. You can find manual by this link NetSpell - [Spell Checker for .NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5277/NetSpell-Spell-Checker-for-NET) in Using the Library section.

There is also possibility to add in your WinForms application control named ElementHost. It will allow you to insert in your application WPF TextBox. And you will be able to set SpellCheck.IsEnabled property for this TextBox inside ElementHost.

Here is nice link about ElementHost: [Hosting WPF controls in a WinForms application](https://dzone.com/articles/hosting-wpf-controls-winforms)

Comment: I have update the answer. But would like to recommend you better to use control ElementHost with WPF TextBox inside

Comment: ElementHost not in framework 3.5 ;(

Comment: No, it's exists .Net 3.5. In controls it could be found at WPF Interoperability tab

Comment: OK thanks dear ........