# how to check spelling mistakes from two text-boxes

Tags: vb.net

i want to compare two text box( data/strings in both text-box). spelling mistakes.if spelling mistakes is occur then that word should be highlighted.

```
enter code here
```

Public Class Form1

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

End Sub
```

End Class

rd should highlight

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23834001/how-to-activate-spellcheck-in-c-sharp-windows-form-application

Answer (score 0):

This will get very large.  I'm not gonna tell you all of this.  You should make a seperate file with all the possible words (i would copy and paste from a dictionary) and make a read all lines function.  Let a timer check that if a space is entered.  The highlight will need to be created with a RICH textbox. 
I'm not familiar with rich textboxes,  search it up. 
For more questions jist ask.

Comment: Personally I would use a `HashSet(Of T)` as it provides much faster lookup than normally iterating an array. The `HashSet` could then simply be serialized to/deserialized from a file.