# readonly c# - No suitable Method found to override in a customized winforms textbox

Tags: c#, wpf

I have created a spellcheck functionality in the winforms text-box. By following the below accepted answer.

[Trying to use the C# SpellCheck class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4024798/trying-to-use-the-c-sharp-spellcheck-class?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Now my problem is i want to make my textbox to be readonly in some cases. But it seems to be the readonly property is not working when i try the following

`spellbox.Readonly = true`

I even tried to add the following method to the class but it shows error as "**No suitable method found to override**"

```
    [DefaultValue(true)]
     public override bool ReadOnly 
{ get {box.Readonly;} set {box.Readonly = value;} }
```

Code:

```
    using System;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization;
    using System.Windows;
    using System.Windows.Controls;
    using System.Windows.Forms.Integration;
    using System.Windows.Forms.Design;

    namespace Activity_Tracker_Coding
    {
        [Designer(typeof(ControlDesigner))]
        //[DesignerSerializer("System.Windows.Forms.Design.ControlCodeDomSerializer, System.Design, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a", "System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomSerializer, System.Design, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a")]
        class SpellBox : ElementHost
        {
            public SpellBox()
            {
                box = new TextBox();
                base.Child = box;
                box.TextChanged += (s, e) => OnTextChanged(EventArgs.Empty);
                box.SpellCheck.IsEnabled = true;

                box.VerticalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Auto;
                this.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 20);
            }
            public override string Text
            {
                get { return box.Text; }
                set { box.Text = value; }
            }

            [DefaultValue(false)]
            public bool Multiline
            {
                get { return box.AcceptsReturn; }
                set { box.AcceptsReturn = value; }
            }
            [DefaultValue(false)]
            public bool WordWrap
            {
                get { return box.TextWrapping != TextWrapping.NoWrap; }
                set { box.TextWrapping = value ? TextWrapping.Wrap : TextWrapping.NoWrap; }
            }
            [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]
            public new System.Windows.UIElement Child
            {
                get { return base.Child; }
                set { /* Do nothing to solve a problem with the serializer !! */ }
            }
            private TextBox box;

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the code in the link it's using the WPF TextBox control. The property for readonly in WPF is `IsReadOnly`.

Answer (score 0):

I can see that you're inheriting from [`ElementHost`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.integration.elementhost?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2) object, which doesn't contain a `ReadOnly` property.

What you should actually do then is just create your own, inside your `SpellBox` class, without overriding. This property will then access the `TextBox` read only property.

```
[DefaultValue(true)]
public bool ReadOnly 
{ 
    get 
    {
        return box.Readonly;
    } 
    set 
    {
        box.Readonly = value;
    } 
}
```