# Issue with spell check class

Tags: vb.net, class, textbox, spell-checking

I 'am trying to use [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4024798/trying-to-use-the-c-sharp-spellcheck-class) (posted 11 years ago !), and I have problems with the vb.net version. I have solved a lot of compilation errors, but I can't solve this one :

```
MyBase.Child = box
```

Which returns the error ***'Cannot convert a value of type 'TextBox' to 'UIElement'***. I tried casting and a lot of other things, but as a real newbie I don't understand what could be wrong. And as a newbie on this forum, I can't ask within a comment in the original question...

Comment: What type of project are you creating? `UIElement` is a WPF type and the WPF `TextBox` does indeed inherit that class. If you're creating a Windows Forms app then obviously that `TextBox` isn't derived from `UIElement`.

Comment: BTW, please read tag descriptions before using tags. The VS tag description specifically states that it is for issues with the IDE, not code that just happens to be written in VS.

Answer (score 0):

In the question you linked to, the accepted answer contains code for a class that inherits `ElementHost`, which is a WinForms class that exists specifically to host WPF controls. That means that the `TextBox` in that code is a WPF `TextBox`. Note the namespace imports in that code. It's the `System.Windows.Controls.TextBox` control that is being used. I suspect that you either don't have that namespace imported or have the `System.Windows.Forms` namespace imported preferentially and thus, in your code, `TextBox` is actually being interpreted as `System.Windows.Forms.TextBox`.

Comment: You're right, my app is a Windows Form App. I have exactly the same imports as the question I linked to. Adding `System.Windows.Controls.TextBox` did not fix the issue. Removing `Imports System.Windows.Forms.Integration` did it but generates some other issues. I need more time to read about controls, WPF and WF because I'am a little bit confused with this...Thank you so much for your support !

Comment: @Mika, *"Adding `System.Windows.Controls.TextBox`"* could mean numerous different things. How ever you do it, you need to make sure that you are using the `System.Windows.Controls.TextBox` class in that code. If you need to fully-qualify the name, i.e. use `private System.Windows.Controls.TextBox box;`, then do that.

Comment: Thank for the support. As I did not manage to get out of this issue, I have finally used NHunspell which was very easy to manage and now all works fine !

Comment: @Mika, then you should delete this question, as it is no longer relevant. If you still want an answer to this question, you already have it. you simply haven't implemented it properly.

Comment: I tried to delete the question but it tells me that my account will be blocked from asking new questions. So I'am not sure what to do.

Comment: @Mika, I wasn't aware of that. I have flagged your question to the mods and recommended it be deleted as no longer relevant.